# Post em timeline Facebook

Tags: angularjs, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

Eu estou montando um site onde o usuário pode solicitar que conteúdos sejam postados em sua linha do tempo sem ele precisar ficar compartilhando. Bom fiquei com a seguinte dúvida, vendo o retorno deste link: http://plnkr.co/edit/mA7dzreUlqqTJZqodAzv?p=preview, gostaria de saber como posso fazer para mandar um post para o usuário dele, ou se isso só é permitido se ele estiver logado no sistema ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Para publicar na *timeline* do usuário é preciso solicitar uma permissão chamada **publish_actions** e ao solicitar esta permissão seu aplicativo terá de passar por uma [aprovação do Facebook](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/#submitlogin).

Apesar de tudo isso o seu aplicativo não será aprovado. Segundo as [boas praticas do Facebook](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/checklist/v2.2) é proibido postar algo automaticamente na timeline do usuário. Tudo precisa ter interação do mesmo para ser publicado.

Links que valem a leitura antes de começar um aplicativo:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/login
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.2#reference

Também recomendo ficar atualizado com o Blog para desenvolvedores:
https://developers.facebook.com/blog/

Raul.